# Android Intent Category CATEGORY_BROWSABLE

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to add a web page navigation Activity in my Android application, and I find that I need to use CATEGORY_BROWSABLE. The description says:

```
By supporting this category, you are promising that there is nothing damaging 
(without user intervention) that can happen by invoking any matching Intent.
```

Can someone tell what risk is Android is trying to highlight here ? What could be damaging in handling web page navigation ?

Answer (score 0):

Operations such as invasive edits to an account, deleting contacts and text messages, downloading files without user permission, etc. are considered damaging without user intervention.

As this category can be added to any activity (webview-based or not), the line you quoted is meant as a general rule of thumb for developers who decide to flag their activities (webview-based or not) as BROWSABLE.